# Linux: What happens to active threads hooked into system monitors when a process is killed?

Tags: linux, multithreading, kill

I've written a [tool](http://github.com/slashmais/simplebup) that uses inotify watches to monitor directory changes. It starts a separate thread per watched directory, each using inotify to setup the watch.

What happens to these threads/watches if the parent process is terminated with kill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they belong to the same process, they will be cleaned up.

Comment: Will the watches added to inotifty also be removed? What happens if it isn't?

Comment: They will be cleaned as well. Generally, all resources are cleaned up unless the docs specifically say otherwise (semaphores would be an example).